# JS this.function is not a function in promise

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-class

I'm trying to process a queue, in which I'm calling a class function that is querying an api.
But no matter what I try, I get the error

```js
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.getVisitorData is not a function
```

This is my queue in index.js

```js
# index.js
(async (ppc) => {

    const lander = new landingPage();

    // run the queued calls from the snippet to be processed
    for (let i = 0, l = ppc.queue.length; i < l; i++) {
        await lander.queue.apply(ppc, ppc.queue[i])
    }

})(window.ppc)
```

This is the class landingPage queue method:

```js
# landing_page.js
// process window.pcc queue
    async queue(method, value, data) {

        if (method === 'init') {

            config.propertyId = value

        } else if (method === 'event') {

            // Do no track if visitor opted out
            if (!await optOut()) {
                new ppcEvent(value, data)
            }

        } else if (method === 'options' && value === 'visitor') {

            const data = await this.getVisitorData()
            this.customizeLander(data)
        }
    }
```

And this is the class landingPage method to query the api

```js
# landing_page.js
async getVisitorData() {
        const key = 'landing_page_customization'
        let visitor = helpers.isset(window.sessionStorage.getItem(key))

        if (!visitor) {
            try {
                const [geo, device] = await axios.all([axios.get(config.geoEndpoint), axios.get(config.deviceEndpoint)]);

                const visitor = {
                    ...geo.data,
                    ...device.data,
                }

                window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(visitor))

                return visitor

            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err.message);
            }
        }

        return JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem(key))
    }
```

I even tried removing the async from `visitorData`, but I'm seeing the same error then.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Because you’re very explicitly binding another `this` through `apply`…?

Comment: `lander.queue.apply(ppc, ppc.queue[i])` - you're calling `queue` and setting `this` to be `ppc`. Apparently, `ppc` does not have a `getVisitorData()` method. If you expect to use the one from `landingPage`, *don't override `this`*

Comment: Yes, that was it. Haha, perfect explanation @VLAZ
Please add this as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Thanks @deceze also! Since Vlaz explained it in more detail I will accept his answer, even though you we're a bit faster ;) Thanks everybody, it makes absolute sense now where I went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to `apply()` is the value that should be `this` in the function being called. Since `queue` is a method of the `landingPage` class, you should pass an instance of that class as the first argument. Apparently `ppc` is not a `landingPage`, but `lander` is. So change the line to

```
await lander.queue.apply(lander, ppc.queue[i])
```

You can also use ES6 spread notation instead of `apply`:

```
await lander.queue(...ppc.queue[i]);
```

Comment: Would absolutely upvote that for the tip about es6 syntax, sadly I do not have sufficient reputation (15) yet. I appreciate your comment though!

Comment: Since you're the questioner, you vote by accepting the answer.

Comment: I will accept yours, but first I want to give Vlaz time to make his comment a reply. He was first to give a thorough reply. Yours is more detailed though :)

Comment: If he hasn't posted an answer by now, he's probably not going to. He might have been the one who suggested the ES6 syntax to me, I don't remember.

Comment: Yeah you're probably right :) And i got the extra with the spread syntax from you, so I don't have to pass in any object!!